# Fprintf VS _ftprintf

Tags: c, printf, filestream

both have almost same input parameters:

```
int _ftprintf( FILE *stream, const _tchar *format [, argument ]...)

int fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...)
```

What is the difference between the two format agruments?
When should I use each?

Comment: `fprintf` is standard C, I don;t know about `_ftprintf`

Comment: What OS, what API, does this apply to?

Comment: [`_ftprintf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh07fe2.aspx) is a Visual C (and C++) specific "function" which is actually a macro the expands to another function in the `printf` family depending on the `_UNICODE` and `_MBCS` macros. There's a table in the reference to say what it expands to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_tprintf` and `_ftprintf` are to be used with `TCHAR` format strings. `TCHAR` is just a macro, which unwraps into either `char` or `wchar_t`, depending on whether is the `_UNICODE` macro defined.

So, basically, if you don't have `_UNICODE` defined, `_ftprintf` will be equivalent to `fprintf`, otherwise it will be equivalent to `fwprintf`.

Comment: Thanks Eldar, and when _UNICODE is defined?

Comment: @ItayAvraham `Project Properties -> General -> Project Defaults -> Character Set`. If `Use Unicode Character Set` is set, MSBuild will define it implicitly.