# Undefined Windows reference _ftprintf

Tags: c, winapi, printf, cygwin, undefined-reference

I just recently installed GCC onto Windows through [Cygwin64](https://cygwin.com/install.html). I am trying to compile a program that contains the Windows `_ftprintf` function [(as shown here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecCrypto/example-c-program-using-cryptacquirecontext) in the MyHandleError Function and [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fprintf-fprintf-l-fwprintf-fwprintf-l?view=vs-2017#generic-text-routine-mappings)), however, I am getting an undefined reference.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

void main(void){
    _ftprintf(stderr, TEXT("Test Err. \n"));
}
```

The following example produces the following error when compiling as `gcc test.c`:

```
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:6:5: warning: implicit declaration of function '_ftprintf'; did you mean '__eprintf'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 _ftprintf(stderr, TEXT("Test Err. \n"));
 ^~~~~~~~~
 __eprintf
/cygdrive/c/Users/Dan/AppData/Local/Temp/ccEa2phm.o:test.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `_ftprintf'
/cygdrive/c/Users/Dan/AppData/Local/Temp/ccEa2phm.o:test.c:(.text+0x21): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `_ftprintf'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Am I missing a flag or something?**

Comment: Is this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454005/fprintf-vs-ftprintf) of interest?

Comment: @WeatherVane It is not. I have seen this question, however, it doesn't answer my question above. I have compiled the following function awhile back (with Sublime and gcc), but I can't seem to understand why I am unable to now.

Comment: Sublime (a text editor) is irrelevant, but perhaps you were using MinGW GCC rather then Cygwin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is declared at all, it will be declared in tchar.h - open that file and check.  However, since the linker also cannot resolve it it would appear that it does not it is not defined in the library at all.

I would not expect this to work in Cygwin which is intended to support the Linux/GNU API on Windows - it is not appropriate if you are targeting the Windows/Microsoft API in any case.  Moreover Cygwin uses UTF-8 rather then Windows UTF-16 encoding so it is not really surprising that Windows' wide-character support is not available.

If you are writing Windows specific code and want to use GCC, then you will be better off using MinGW - it is the GCC compiler with the Windows C run-time library.  A better alternative to Cygwin if you want a (true) Linux execution environment is to use [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) - a thing that renders Cygwin largely obsolete.

Comment: You were absolutely correct! I was actually not aware of the differences between Cygwin and MinGW, so I learned something new. After I installed MinGW and linked the bin files, I was able to compile the code. I specifically am targeting only Windows, so MinGW is needed.

Comment: FWIW, the `TCHAR` stuff is just a bunch of macros in the Windows world -- one would expect `ftprintf` to become either `fprintf` or `fwprintf` depending on how the build has configured the `UNICODE` macro.  One would not expect the name `ftprintf` to survive to link time in any configuration.

Comment: @BenVoigt :  That is a good point since the linker was looking for `ftprintf` in the library _only_ because of the implicit declaration - no such function exists even  when where the `ftprintf` macro is defined.